# How to add support for google home app to my smart bulb?

Tags: android, iot, google-home, google-assist-api, google-weave

We have built a smart bulb which we want to control using the Google Assistant as well(apart from our Android and iOS apps). I searched for this and figured out that we need to implement Google Weave protocol on our bulbs for it to be controllable via Google Assistant.
What I don't understand is how can I add this to Home app so that users can add it as smart bulb to Home app and control via Google Assistant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing the same problem, found my answer here: https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/

At the time I posted my question, this page either did not exist or I did not find it.

This page points to sample implementation for smart home device. Here is the link to github repo: https://github.com/actions-on-google/actionssdk-smart-home-nodejs It also has detailed instructions on how to run the code.

To summarize, we need provide following actions.json(which points to our server which fulfills 3 intents SYNC, QUERY and EXECUTE) file as our Action Package.

```
{
  "actions": [{
    "name": "actions.devices",
    "deviceControl": {
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "conversationName": "automation"
    }
  }],
  "conversations": {
    "automation" :
    {
      "name": "automation",
      "url": "https://<our server which provides fulfillment for SYNC, QUERY and EXECURE intents>"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the link between home and your system via [api.ai](http://api.ai)

The key concepts are [here](https://docs.api.ai/docs/key-concepts). This site creates JSON files which are loaded into the Google Actions API. Once approved you have a keyword or phrase which when said into Google home opens interactions with your system via webhooks.

Comment: I can make link between Google Home and my server using api.ai to define dialogs and provide fulfilment. What I want to know is how can I list my smart bulbs under 'Home Control' just like Hue, Lifx, Honeywell and other device are listed.